# FFMPEG - converting interlaced 720x480 MPEG2 to scaled up progressive 1440x1080 HEVC (Nvidia available)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to improve the video of a ripped DVD. The current file is encoded in MPEG2 interlaced and 720:480. I am trying see if it is possible, with a bit of conversion, for it to look better... possibly upscaling to near-HD if it is possible. My computer does have an Nvida (1050 Ti) card, so I was thinking that may help.

I used

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i "input.mkv" -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset p7 -profile:v 1 -level 0 -tier 1 -tune 1 -vf yadif -vf "scale=1440x1080:flags=lanczos" -c:a aac -c:s srt output.mkv
```

The "-vf yadif" portion in that was intended to de-interlace, after looking at ideas on de-interlacing but the output still ends up being interlaced. The interlace artifact is quite annoying when viewed on my computer.

Comment: Your first filter `-vf yadif` has no effect. This is only the last filter that will be executed. Put the two together : `-vf yadif,scale=1440x1080:flags=lanczos`